# Supersede PPA package with a new one

Tags: ppa

I have a package named `maike_0.16.1-1milasudril1.deb` compiled for Zesty. I have uploaded a newer version for Xenial, with name  `maike_0.17.0-1milasudril1.deb`, and want to push one for Zesty as well. I thought launchpad could be smart enough to put these packages in different categories based on the release tag, but it does not use that information. Instead the package name has to be different, so I tried to put Zesty in different places, but it does not take it. Is this because it assumes

```
`0.16.1-few extra letters` > `0.17.0-other extra letters`
```

or what is going on. Can I fix the issue without bumping upstream version number?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to not include the source tar-ball, with the command

```
 debuild -S -sd
```